# How to check if PC is bluetooth capable?

Tags: java, swing, bluetooth, installation

I was given a task to develop a desktop application in Swing (Java). Before the installation (or during) I need to check whether the PC has blue-tooth capabilities, amognst others.

Is there a config file, where this can be done or do I have to do it in code?

Comment: Check this link http://bluecove.org/, maybe it helps you.

Comment: but I was told that there is some sort of a installation file that I need to investigate for our project..?

Comment: *"but I was told that"*  Go back and ask whoever told you that for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Use java bluetooth library like [bluecove](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove) to check that existing pc is having bluetooth or not.